# Install MPFR 3.X on Apple M1

Tags: apple-m1, mpfr

I am on Apple M1. I tried to install a special package (Vienna RNA Package, precompiled binary package, https://www.tbi.univie.ac.at/RNA/#pack_macosx).
Installation is finished, but when I type the following

```
$ RNAduplex
```

I get the following:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/mpfr/lib/libmpfr.4.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/RNAfold
  Reason: image not found
Abort trap: 6
```

Mpfr is installed via homebrew, but only the most recent version (4.1.0). I guess I need to install the previous version (3.1.6), but I don't get it work.
I tried to install it from https://www.mpfr.org/mpfr-3.1.6/ downloaded from https://www.mpfr.org/mpfr-3.1.6/.
When I do

```
./configure
```

I get

```
configure: error: gmp.h can't be found, or is unusable.
```

even though gmp is already installed via homebrew (present at /opt/homebrew/Cellar/gmp/).

Any advice on this?
Looking forward to any comments!
Best,
Stefanie

Answer (score 0):

The `config.log` file may give more information about the error, but I suppose that `gmp.h` isn't in the include search path. You can try something similar, by compiling:

```
#include <gmp.h>
int main (void) { return 0; }
```

You will probably get an error as well.

So you may need to add the directory where `gmp.h` has been installed to the `CPATH` or `C_INCLUDE_PATH` environment variable. You will need to do something similar for the library. Another solution is to use the `--with-gmp=...` configure option with the GMP installation directory. See the `INSTALL` file for more information.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the comment. I now managed to install mpfr 3.1.6 by using the `--with-gmp= ... ` option. However, it's seems to be wrong archtitecture for my laptop. When I now run 
`RNAfold` I get: 



```/usr/local/lib/libmpfr.4.dylib: mach-o, but wrong architecture```

Comment: @SteffiEbersberger Perhaps the `RNAfold` binary package is for x86, as [macOS Big Sur](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_Big_Sur) (first ARM version) is quite recent: 12 November 2020. In such a case, you need to rebuild `RNAfold` from source (and you can use the latest MPFR version).

Comment: Issue solved. Building from source worked perfectly fine. Thanks!